# How to subtract from a user-inputed list

Tags: python, list, user-input, subtraction

I am trying to subtract numbers from a list that the user enters.
For example, I have this for addition which works the way I want it to:

```
print("\nAddition")
n = int(input('How many numbers are you adding?: '))
L = []
for i in range(n):
    L.append(int(input("Enter a number: ")))
    answer = sum(L)
    print(answer)
```

How do I go about doing the same for subtraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For subtraction you could loop yourself and subtract:

```
result = L[0]
for num in L[1:]:
    result -= num
```

This presumes that you want to start with the first number and subtract all the other numbers from that first value.

You could still use `sum()` but then you'd have to [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) all but the first number to negative:

```
from operator import neg

result = sum(map(neg, L[1:]), L[0])
```

The [`operator.neg()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.neg) negates numbers, and we make use of the second argument to [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) to provide a start value.

Demo:

```
>>> from operator import neg
>>> L = [42, 10, 3, 8]
>>> sum(map(neg, L[1:]), L[0])
21
```